# bad javascript? hello bar solo only working on homepage - no other pages

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

I'm running a bigcommerce store and have the hello bar solo custom code installed in the site footer. I've also tried placement of the hellobar code in various spots (header template files, default template files, page specific template files).  For some reason the hello-bar only works on my homepage, but never on any of the other pages.

Any ideas as to why?  Seems like if i place this in the footer it should show up on every pages but that's not what i'm getting.  please let me know if you need more details or code samples to help.

thanks

btw, bigcommerce support also thinks that the hellobar should show up on every page if i have this code in the footer, but its not working.  my guess is that it's the javascript but I dont know my way around that.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
   <div id="mailchimp_form" style="display:none;">
<form action="http://xxxxx.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="xxxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="xxxxx">
Get an instant coupon code by signing up to our newsletter.  Email: <input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" size="25" value="" />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
</div>
<!-- Hello Bar configuration start -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var mailChimpForm = document.getElementById('mailchimp_form').innerHTML;
new HelloBar( mailChimpForm, {
    showWait: 1000,
    positioning: 'sticky',
    fonts: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    forgetful: true
}, 1.0 );
</script>
```

And here are the references that I've placed in the header:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="content/hellobar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="content/hellobar.js"></script>
```

Comment: can we see that happening live somewhere??

Answer (score 0):

No idea what bigcommerce is, but judging from what you supplied I am guessing one of two reasons.

1. There is no 'mailchimp_form' div except on your homepage.
2. Javascript, for some weird reason, does get executed before 'mailchimp_form' div gets loaded on all other pages.